# Kubernetes pod scheduling with replication and local persistent volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Hi i have this problem in kubernetes. I install a deployment with helm that consists of 2 pods i have to put them in two nodes but i want that the persistent volume used by the pods are in the same nodes as the pod are deployed. Is feasible in helm? Thanks

Comment: Usually Kubernetes handles this itself.  (Helm doesn't really come into it; it's just a way of creating the YAML that describes your deployments.)  Can you give an example of your current setup and how it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Local Persistent Volume
See more: [local-pv](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local), [local-pv-comparision](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/#how-is-it-different-from-a-hostpath-volume).

**Usage of Local Persistent Volumes**:

> The local volumes must still first be set up and mounted on the local
> node by an administrator. The administrator needs to mount the local
> volume into a configurable “discovery directory” that the local volume
> manager recognizes. Directories on a shared file system are supported,
> but they must be bind-mounted into the discovery directory.
>
> This local volume manager monitors the discovery directory, looking
> for any new mount points. The manager creates a PersistentVolume
> object with the appropriate storageClassName, path, nodeAffinity, and
> capacity for any new mount point that it detects. These
> PersistentVolume objects can eventually be claimed by
> PersistentVolumeClaims, and then mounted in Pods.
>
> After a Pod is done using the volume and deletes the
> PersistentVolumeClaim for it, the local volume manager cleans up the
> local mount by deleting all files from it, then deleting the
> PersistentVolume object. This triggers the discovery cycle: a new
> PersistentVolume is created for the volume and can be reused by a new
> PersistentVolumeClaim.
>
> Local volume can be requested in exactly the same way as any other
> PersistentVolume type: through a PersistentVolumeClaim. Just specify
> the appropriate StorageClassName for local volumes in the
> PersistentVolumeClaim object, and the system takes care of the rest!

In your case I will create manually storageclass and use it during chart installation.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-local-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: example-local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/disks/v1
```

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: example-local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
```

and override default PVC storageClassName configuration during helm install like this:

```
$ helm install --name chart-name --set persistence.storageClass=example-local-storage
```

Take a look: [using-local-pv](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/), [pod-local-pv](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/#using-local-volumes-in-a-pod), [kubernetes-1.19-lv](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/08/26/kubernetes-release-1.19-accentuate-the-paw-sitive/).

Comment: can local volume of different nodes sync/replicate data with each other?